# Break a while loop without using If or Break

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, break

I need to create a program that uses while to find the volume of a cylinder. I need the while loop to break if the user inputs a negative value for the height. My code looks like this:

```
double sentinel=1, h=1, v=0, r, count=0; // declares all variables needed
    final double PI=3.14159;
    boolean NotNegative=true;

while(NotNegative){// && count==0){ // while both the height is positive AND the total times run is 0
        System.out.print("Enter height (Use negative to exit): "); // has the user input the height
        h=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        sentinel=h; // save sentinel as the inputted height

        while(sentinel>0){

           System.out.print("Enter radius: "); // have the user input the radius
           r=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
           v=PI*(r*r)*h; // find the volume
           System.out.println("The volume is " + v); // print out the volume
           count++; // increase the count each time this runs
           NotNegative=true;
           sentinel=-1;
        }
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: And why don't you want break or if ?

Comment: Is `Math.PI` too accurate? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an Exception which you catch and ignore.  This is bad idea as

- if and/or break is more efficient and simpler.
- it's slow
- it's confusing.

However, since you are using a while loop, which is like using an if & break, you can do the following.

```
NotNegative = h >= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code inside the `while(NotNegative){`, after reading the input.

```
NotNegative = h >= 0;
```